# Groovy string replacing token with dollar symbol from variable not working

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
props = readProperties  file: "src/main/resources/application-DEV.properties";
def DB_HOST         = (props['com_db_url'].split(':')[2]).replace('//', '');
def DB_USER         = props['com_db_username'];
def DB_PASSWORD     = props['com_db_password'];
def DB_PORT         = (props['com_db_url'].split(':')[3]).split('/')[0];
def jsonData = "{'$DB_HOST':'${DB_HOST}','$DB_USER':'${DB_USER}','$DB_PASSWORD':'${DB_PASSWORD}','$DB_PORT':'${DB_PORT}'}";
String filenew = readFile('dev/values-dev.yaml')
def jsonObject = readJSON text: jsonData;

jsonObject.each { key, value ->
    def _key = "${key}";
    _key = '\\\\'+_key
    echo "$key : $value, custom key : ${_key}"
    filenew = filenew.replaceAll("${_key}", '$value')
}
```

My **values-dev.yaml** file as follows

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
config:
  autoDiscoverDatabases: true
  datasource:
    host: $DB_HOST
    user: $DB_USER
    password: $DB_PASSWORD
    port: $DB_PORT
    sslmode: "require"
    database: "ibmclouddb"
```

I have tried multiple ways in last 4 days to replace token using for loop, but hard luck.
With following way it is working for me

```
//filenew = filenew.replaceAll('\\$DB_HOST', jsonObject.DB_HOST)
//filenew = filenew.replaceAll('\\$DB_USER', jsonObject.DB_USER)
//filenew = filenew.replaceAll('\\$DB_PASSWORD', jsonObject.DB_PASSWORD)
//filenew = filenew.replaceAll('\\$DB_PORT', jsonObject.DB_PORT)
```

Purposefully I have prepended `$` symbol variables in JSON data, i.e. in above `jsonData` variable declared initially.

But I wanted to achieve this via a generic way.

Answer (score 2):

All the replacements can be done in one step and there is no need to use
an interim JSON map.

Just build a map with all the replacements you know.  Then use
`replaceAll` with a regexp, that catches your replacement keys and use
a closure to handle the replacement.  The closure simply looks up the
key in your replacements and has some means to generate some error, if
a replacement is unknown (or you could just write the key back).

```
def replacements = [
  DB_USER: "the user",
  // ...
]

def yaml = '''
config:
  autoDiscoverDatabases: true
  datasource:
    host: $DB_FAILS
    user: $DB_USER
'''

println yaml.replaceAll(/\$([A-Z_]+)/, { _, k -> replacements.getOrDefault(k, "FAILED TO REPLACE $k") })
// →
// config:
//   autoDiscoverDatabases: true
//   datasource:
//     host: FAILED TO REPLACE DB_FAILS
//     user: the user
```

Comment: Hi @cfrick I am always getting `null` value
`
datasource:
22:51:37      host: FAILED TO REPLACE null
22:51:37      user: FAILED TO REPLACE null
22:51:37      password: FAILED TO REPLACE null
22:51:37      port: FAILED TO REPLACE null
`

Answer (score 1):

Here a simpler solution which works in a generic way as you wish.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String props = '''
    user: $DB_USER
    pass: $DB_PASS
'''

def DB_USER = 'com_db_username'
def DB_PASS = 'com_db_password'
def jsonData = $/
    {
        "$$DB_USER":"${DB_USER}",
        "$$DB_PASS":"${DB_PASS}",
    }/$

//println jsonData

def jsonObject =  new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonData)
jsonObject.each { key, value ->
    props = props.replaceAll(/\$key/, value)
}
println props
```

with the output:

```
    user: com_db_username
    pass: com_db_password
```

The trickiest part is the regex expression and the escaping and what kind of string to use for it for a convenient escaping. In the regex expression `/\$key/` the exapnded value of `$key` will be `$DB_USER` which will output the `$` sign that must be also escaped with the `\` before.

I had to adapt your code, to work without a Jenkins server.
One error I had to fix is that your JSON do not use double-quotes for key-values. To fix it without mess up the interpolation, I used a groovy dollar-slashy string which is more readable and flexible. In the $-slashy strings you need to escape only the $ signs, everything else can be left as it is without escaping.
For simplicity, instead of yaml file I use just string, for the properties I defined some variables and I reduced everything to 2 variables.

Comment: The problem with this solution I am facing is, I am not able to import JsonSplurr lib, since we have restrictions to import any of external libraries. Here is too much restrictive areas. And I have to stick to basic libs only.

Comment: You don't have to. I used it because I tested it on a local machine where I do not have readJson which is available only on Jenkins. Just replace JsonSlurper with readJson from your example and everything works fine.

Comment: Do I need to modify my JSON data structure?, since you mentioned two dollar symbols on key side as below:-
"$$DB_USER":"${DB_USER}",
Is it necessary ?

Comment: No. I used dollar-slashy string because it is more convenient when it comes to escaping strings. It makes everything more readable.

Comment: Is there any other simpler way without including dollar symbols ? because this is still character dependent. If I remove dollar symbol from string, it works without any error but does not replace the tokens.